# android: paint onto ARGB bitmap without changing alpha channel

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, alpha

I want to use paint to change the color values of an ARGB bitmap.

I want to keep the original alpha values from the bitmap. 
I dont want to make any change to the alpha values in the bitmap. I need them to stay the same. The alpha values are different in each pixel and must be preserved.

How can i restrict the channels that paint alters the values for?

Comment: I suspect you want `Paint.setXfermode()` with `PorterDuff.Mode.DST`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @fadden, a useful lead: according to this fantastic document on [PorterDuffModes](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html} I will try ATOP and IN

Comment: @kodintent: +1 for the great link. Thank you for sharing!